# web.config transformation and the location element

Tags: asp.net, web-config, web-config-transform

I cannot seem to work out how you would change the following

```
<configuration>
<location path="hello123">
<.../>
</location>
</configuration>
```

to

```
<configuration>
<location path="world321">
<.../>
</location>
</configuration>
```

without removing the first and adding the second. Any help with this would be great.

Thanks

Comment: What are you using to do the transformation?  Is it some type of XSLT or is it in code?

Comment: VS2010 has it built in - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx

Comment: The reason I want to avoid removing and then adding is because the allow/deny conditions may change within the location element and I don't want to have to change the web.config and the transform files. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Oh...  nice!  I hadn't heard about that, I'll have to read up on it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `SetAttributes`, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <location path="world321" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(path)" >
  </location>
</configuration>
```

You can test this and other transformations on the [AppHarbor web.config transformation tester](http://webconfigtransformationtester.apphb.com/).

Comment: you can also right click on Web.Config.Release and select 'Preview Transform' (in VS2012 for sure and possibly VS2010)